# Getting wrong hex value from read function

Tags: c++, hex, readfile, ifstream

Function gets valid data by 1 step, but when go to 2 step gets wrong hex data, what i`m doing wrong?

```
stringstream getHexFromBuffer(char* buffer,short startFrom = 0, short to = 4)
{
    int len = strlen(buffer);
    stringstream hexValue;
    for (size_t i = startFrom; i < to; i++) {
        hexValue << hex << (int)buffer[i];
    }
    return hexValue;
}

bool big::openFile(std::string fName){
    this->fileName = fName;
    
    ifstream file(fName.c_str(), ios::binary | ios::out | ios::ate);

    char* memblock;

    this->fileSize = file.tellg();

    memblock = new char[16];

    file.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        file.close();
        throw new exception("Файл не может быть открыт!");
    }
    file.read(memblock, 16);
    string bigCheck = hexToASCII(getHexFromBuffer(memblock).str());

    if (strcmp(bigCheck.c_str(), "BIGF") != 0) {
        throw new exception("Не .BIG архив!");
    }
    this->fileType = bigCheck.c_str();

    string bigSize = getHexFromBuffer(memblock, 4, 8).str();
    //cout << getIntFromHexString(bigSize) << endl << this->fileSize ;

    file.close();
}
```

[First valid attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Wo2.png)

[Second not valid attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dZ4g.png)

*Must be* **d0998100**, but get **ffffffd0ffffff99ffffff810** instead

Full hex that i trying to get is 42 49 47 46 D0 99 81 00, maybe it helps

Comment: Why do you mix input file stream `ifstream` with the output flag`ios::out`?

Comment: that i just try add some params, when i found that read func returns me wrong value, but didn`t work

Comment: D0 is a negative 8 bit value in char. This is exact the same negative value ffffffd0 in int.

Comment: Huh, thanks, didn`t know that)
What i need to do to get "INT32 - Little Endian (DCBA)" or reverse that string, custom parser of str?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d0` is a negative 8 bit value in signed char. This is exact the same negative value `ffffffd0` in int. For getting "d0" in output, cast the signed char to another unsigned type of the same size (1 byte) then cast the result to int:

```
hexValue << hex << (int)(unsigned char)buffer[i];
hexValue << hex << (int)(uint8_t)buffer[i];
```

The first type cast keeps 8 bits in an unsigned type, a positive number, the second cast makes a positive int.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are best from the best*